# Memory buildup in Node streams

Tags: node.js

tl;dr: if you have multiple steps in a stream process (A -> B -> C), and the start of the stream (A -> B) is able to pull in data much faster than the output stream is able to send it off (B -> C), does that cause a buildup in memory consumption?

I'm still a beginner at Node streams and want to check in about my understanding...

I'm building a tool that pulls down photos from S3, streams them into a zip archive, and streams that into an S3 upload. I was using streams because I thought it would be possible to have data move quickly and not take up too much memory.

However I'm finding that the memory does steadily grow as the script runs and pulls down more and more photos (we're talking on the order of 1,000s of photos).

My question is whether this is due to an issue of backpressure in the system, e.g. that the upload stream is not sending off data as quickly as the download streams are piping into the zip stream.

Here's the code with a bunch of error handling and logging omitted for clarity.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const s3Zip = require('s3-zip')

exports.handler = function (event, context) {
  const { region, bucket, folder, files, zipFileName } = event
  /**
   * s3Zip.archive is a library call that reads multiple S3 objects using #getObject().createReadStream() and pipes
   * them into a zip using the `archiver` library
   */
  const body = s3Zip.archive({ region, bucket }, folder, files)
  /**
   * s3.upload takes a stream Body and uploads it to s3
   * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property
   */
  const upload = s3.upload({ Bucket: bucket, Key: zipFileName, Body: body })
  upload.send((err, result) => { /* error handling or trigger a success */ })
}
```

Comment: Do not see any stream related logic, like writable.pipe(readable), pump(first, second, third) or pipeline, not sure I follow the issue ...

Comment: Sorry, I'll change the example a bit. The libraries are all working with streams but it's not exactly obvious.

Comment: I'd like to avoid using the base implementation with all the `.createReadStream()`s and such. If the code doesn't make sense, hopefully it's still possible to answer the question in the abstract?